# Command not found error after changing virtual machine

Tags: discord.py

Okay so I have a music bot code that was working before I switched to another virtual machine provider. All the requirements are exactly the same as in my previous virtual machine because I copy and pasted everything including the `requirements.txt`. The bot runs normally with 0 errors until I try to run any of the commands. It gave me this error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "play" is not found
```

I've tried rolling back to the rewrite version I started the project on,
changed `@client.command` to `@bot.command` after assigning `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='prefix')`

```py
#I've assigned client = discord.ext.commands
@client.command(name='play', aliases=['sing'])
async def play(self, ctx, *, search: str):
    #then some code
```

update 1: Ran it as a cog and raised:

`discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'music' raised an error: TypeError: cogs must derive from Cog`

update 2: No idea why rolling back the rewrite version didn't work though. Perhaps I didn't do it correctly.

Comment: Is this in a cog?  Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I used to run in as a standalone bot and not in a cog. I just tried running it in a cog and it raised this:
```discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'music' raised an error: TypeError: cogs must derive from Cog``` @PatrickHaugh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply run it as a cog.

Note that the way cogs work has been updated recently:

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html

If you still want to run it as a standalone bot,
your bot should looks like something along the lines of:

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

bot = Bot("!")

@bot.command(name='play', aliases=['sing'])
async def play(ctx, *, search: str):  # Note no self
    #then some code

bot.run("token")
```

It's important that the bot that you run is the same bot that you register the commands with.  You're also passing `self` to your bot even though it's not in a cog, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found the problem.
The bot doesnt work when I try to run it as a standalone bot.
The reason using it as a cog don't work the first time was because.
the way cogs work has been changed in discord.py rewrite.
These are the changes I made:

```py
#in cogs/music.py
class Music:
    #Code

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Music bot online')
```

to

```py
#in cogs/music.py
class Music(commands.Cog):
    #Code

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_ready():
    print('Music bot online')
```

Thank you to the legendary @PatrickHaugh for helping me figure this out.